# How can I fix "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" WebPart error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to add a Media and Content Web-part (Page Viewer) on a page.  Unfortunately when I add the link I get the message "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" "To help protect the security of the information you enter into this site, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame"

Note when I test the link from within the page I have no issues opening the link.  Note the link is not within my SharePoint site, but it is within our organization website.  I have had no issues with adding other Page Viewers so this is puzzling.  The page I am trying to add (via Page Viewer) I is an Org Chart so I am unsure if perhaps there is special security on the page ?  Note the Org Chart URL is outside of my Site Collection (Division), but the URL is within my company's Main Site Collection

Again though if I click on "Test Link" from my SharePoint site page where I am trying to add the web-part I have no issue opening the page.

I simply just want to embed this Org Chart into my site.  Any suggestions ?  Note since the org chart is dynamic my hope was to embed the page as I do not want to have to save and reload the page each month.

Comment: What are the F12 Developer Console detailed error messages? Most likely one server doesn't allow its content to be framed

Comment: Thr only thing I see is tag can not be self closing.  Use an explicit closing tag.

Comment: Check the network tab, content is coming from someplace else and returning an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the network traffic in your browser (F12 -> network -> something like a play button to start the capture) and check the answer from that page when you try to display it in the page viewer.

Maybe it sends you the header which doesn't allow SharePoint to display this page. Take a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Then the page you want to be displayed needs a change.