# this content can not be displayed in a frame

Tags: 2013, error, iframe, page-viewer-web-part

I can't add a page URL in page viewer web part I am getting this error

[image]

Has anyone faced this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" WebPart error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166057/how-can-i-fix-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame-webpart-error)

Comment: Please add more details, like your browser type and version, the page URL that you trying to add maybe the publisher of this URL does not allow to display his URL in a frame so try different url to trace the issue, also may be browser setting so try to check https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame/a24b93c8-006c-4280-ba1f-01053665e22f

Comment: the duplicate link not helpful, I am using internet explorer / chrome, the page URL is Facebook!

Comment: I think you are trying to display content with a mixed security. You can turn off an associated setting e.g. on IE's settings for seeing if the content can be seen without having the security setting enabled, but that's an user-specific setting.